# Is the dual of continuous functions with compact support identified with Radon or Baire measures?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, dual-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

I have come across two different versions of the Riesz-Markov theorem, one identifies the dual with Radon measures and the other with Baire measures.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem):

> Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. For any positive linear functional $\varphi$ on the space of continuous compactly supported functions, there is a unique Radon measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that
> $$\forall f \in C_c(X): \quad \varphi(f) = \int_X f(x) d\mu(x).$$

From Reed & Simon's book on functional analysis:

> Let $X$ be a locally compact space. A positive linear functional on the algebra of continuous functions of compact support is of the form $\ell(f) = \int f d\mu$ for some Baire measure $\mu$. A positive linear functional on the algebra of continuous functions vanishing at infinity comes from a measure $\mu$ with total finite mass, that is, $\sup_{A \in \mathscr{B}} \mu (A) < \infty$.

Are these two statements equivalent? My guess is that the two can be shown to be equivalent by using the unique extension of each Baire measure to a regular Borel measure (which I assume will be Radon?).

Comment: The Baire measure in Reed, Simon does not need to be unique in general, so the theorems are not equivalent in the sense that the second does not address the uniqueness issue. There is a unique Baire measure satisfying (one of several possible?) regularity assumptions that represents the functional, though. I believe there's a discussion in Royden's real analysis textbook.

Comment: @user378654 Reed and Simon give another version of the Riesz-Markov theorem where the Baire measure is unique when the space is compact. So when the space is compact the linear functionals are identified with a unique Baire measure, but when we only assume local compactness then we instead have a unique Radon measure? Is that the difference?